# JSON importer for Blender 2.79?

Tags: export, import, blend4web, webgl

Hi is there any importers for blender 2.79 for importing JSON files? 
I have found an importer for 2.50 but this doesn't work for 2.79 nor does it work for 2.50 as after installing the addon on blender 2.57 it doesn't let you enable the addon and will not let you check the enable box.

It's also a bit strange that blend4web doesn't have an importer as it has an exporter for json...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to import ? Json can contain literally every kind of data

Comment: @thibsert an .obj in the forum of json data I don't have the original obj otherwise I'd import that